# mongodb query on uniqueness of a field

Tags: mongodb

doing a prefix search

```
query = ({$or:[{country_lc:/^unit.*/, docType:'country'}, {region_lc:/^unit.*/, docType:'region'}, {city_lc:/^unit.*/, docType:'city'}]})

FIELDS = [
            country : 1
        ,   region  : 1
        ,   city    : 1
        ,   docType : 1
    ]

SORT_RULE = [

           country_lc  : 1
        ,   region_lc   : 1
        ,   city_lc     : 1
    ]

def locCursor = db.location.find(query, FIELDS).sort(SORT_RULE)
```

But this gives me duplicate results as well...So I want disticnt results. The distinction should be on the field
called 'name' in location colection. Means for each unique name,it should five me one result

Comment: Your English is really hard to understand but I believe you are looking to use $group within the aggregation framework.

Comment: how can I use group for this particular problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB shell you can do:

```
db.location.aggregate([
    {$match: {$or:[
        {country_lc:/^unit.*/, docType:'country'}, 
        {region_lc:/^unit.*/, docType:'region'}, 
        {city_lc:/^unit.*/, docType:'city'}
    ]}},
    {$group: {
        _id: '$name', 
        country: '$country', 
        region: '$region', 
        city: '$city', 
        docType: '$docType'
    }},
    {$sort: {couuntry_lc: 1, region_lc: 1, city_lc: 1}}
])
```

To get your results.

Comment: @prashantas oops should have used array

Comment: I didn't get. How can I modify the above query now ?

Comment: @prashantas how do you want to modify it? For reference you should read up on the aggregation framework: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/